# Xamarin.Forms - Listview and entry within the scrollview

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, scrollview

I have a `scrollview` with a `Listview` and `Entry`. Basically, this page is a chat.

The problem resides when i scroll the view, my entry disappears. If the entry is outside the scrollview, the scroll problem no longer occurs but when the entry is focused, the listview does not go to the end.

**My chat page XAML:**

```
 <ScrollView x:Name="scroll">
            <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                <ListView 
                        x:Name="MessagesListView" 
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MessageTemplateSelector}" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Pedidos}" 
                        HasUnevenRows="True"  SeparatorVisibility="None" Grid.Row="0" IsEnabled="True" SelectionMode="None" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource BackGroundColor}"/>

                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource white}" Grid.Row="1" >

                    <local1:CustomEntry 
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  

                    Placeholder="{translator:Translate Mensagem}"  
                    Keyboard="Chat"  Margin="8,0,0,0" PlaceholderColor="{StaticResource PlaceHolderText}" TextColor="{StaticResource texto}"  FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Pedido.Message}" x:Name="Message"/>
                    <Image Source="send.png" WidthRequest="32" HeightRequest="32" Margin="8,8,8,8" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer
                               Command="{Binding EnviarPedidoCommand}"
                               Tapped="Button_Clicked"
                                />
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
```

**My chat code:**

```
 public partial class ChatPage : ContentPage
{
    readonly ViewModels.ConnectionHub _viewModel;
    public ICommand EnviarPedidoCommand { get; set; }
    Classes.ClassConversation.ResultadoConversation GetResult;
    Classes.ClassUser.Result GetUser;

    public ChatPage(Classes.ClassConversation.ResultadoConversation conversation, Classes.ClassUser.Result user)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        GetResult = conversation;
        ConnectionsStrings.GlobalVar.email = user.rowKey;
        GetUser = user;

        Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);

        GetHistoryOfConversation(conversation.rowKey, ConnectionsStrings.GlobalVar.Token, user);

        _viewModel = new ViewModels.ConnectionHub(conversation, user);
        BindingContext = _viewModel;
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();


        GetHistoryOfConversation(GetResult.rowKey, ConnectionsStrings.GlobalVar.Token, GetUser);

        BindingContext = _viewModel;

        await _viewModel.Connect();
    }

    protected override async void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        await _viewModel.Disconnect();
    }

    //Limpa o campo mensagem quando envia mensagem
    private async  void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Message.Text = "";
        var target = _viewModel.Pedidos[_viewModel.Pedidos.Count - 1];
        MessagesListView.ScrollTo(target, ScrollToPosition.End, true);
        await scroll.ScrollToAsync(Message, ScrollToPosition.End, true);

    }

    //Função que recebe o historico de mensagens daquela conversa
    async void GetHistoryOfConversation(string conversationId, string token, Classes.ClassUser.Result user)
    {
        try
        {
            Classes.ClasMessage messages = await Servicos.Servicos.GetHistoryOfConversation(conversationId, token, user, GetResult);
            _viewModel.Pedidos = new ObservableRangeCollection<Classes.SendMessage>(messages.result);

            var target = _viewModel.Pedidos[_viewModel.Pedidos.Count - 1];
            MessagesListView.ScrollTo(target, ScrollToPosition.End, true);
            await scroll.ScrollToAsync(Message, ScrollToPosition.End, true);


            var result = await Servicos.Servicos.ReadConversation(conversationId, GetResult);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            await DisplayAlert(Languages.AppResources.Notifications, Languages.AppResources.ErrorOccurred, "Ok");
        }
    }


    private void Message_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        var target = _viewModel.Pedidos[_viewModel.Pedidos.Count - 1];
        MessagesListView.ScrollTo(target, ScrollToPosition.End, true);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: a ListView should not be nested in a ScrollView

Comment: Use the header and footers if you need views likewise https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance

Comment: I know ListView should not be nested in a ScrollView.  
The problem is that when the listview is focused, it does not detect the keyboard and does not adjust the view. This problem resides when my listview is not nested in a scrollview

Comment: ListView nested in a ScrollView, they will conflict focus，So, you should make sure if this listview get the focus.